# How to convert data from an inapppurchase to the format needed for Fabric Answers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, twitter-fabric

Twitter have launched a new feature for Fabric that allows [tracking of events](http://docs.fabric.io/ios/answers/answers-events.html). In particular it is possible to track a payment using the following API:

```
[Answers logPurchaseWithPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"13.50"]
                 currency:@"USD"
                  success:@YES
                 itemName:@"Answers Shirt"
                 itemType:@"Apparel"
                   itemId:@"sku-350"
         customAttributes:@{}];
```

I want to track payments through in-app purchases.

When a purchase succeeds inside `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` then it is obvious how to get some these parameters. E.g.

```
[Answers logPurchaseWithPrice:skProduct.price
                 currency:???
                  success:@YES
                 itemName:skProduct.localizedDescription
                 itemType:@"in app purchase"
                   itemId:aTransaction.payment.productIdentifier
         customAttributes:@{}];
```

What is the best way to get the currency string which should be an ISO4217 currency code?

Comment: skProduct.priceLocale.localeIdentifier?

Comment: priceLocale was a good clue, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The currency code can be obtained from:

```
[skProduct.priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode]
```